# Isn't it more efficient to $('#id') rather than $('div#id')?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd assume that a selection by ID is cheap because there's a built in function for it. Searching by element then ID will just make it traverse all elements and then check the IDs of those matching elements. Are there any jquery performance comparison charts on selectors?

Comment: Just ran it here: http://jsperf.com/div-vs

Comment: Agree with @DarrenDavies - best way to determine is to test. However, such a simplistic test page may not be a good test when compared against a complex page with loads of divs, nested divs and ids.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/div-vs/2 and if you want more performance use pure js

Comment: @cocco - Should have also compared with native `querySelector`: http://jsperf.com/div-vs/3

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 nah.. i knew mine is faster..

Comment: Obviously, `$('#id')` is faster than `$('div#id')`

In the `second case` evaluation of all `divs` would be happened first then it will find `id` from the `selected divs`, but not in the first case where evaluation take place only for `#id`. See http://jsperf.com/selecter-with-and-without-tag

Comment: @cocco - Yes it's pretty obvious that `getElementById` is the fastest, but the question is, why not? ;)

Comment: because a. getElementById is native b. it's a old syntax . all new syntaxes are slower than old ones or jquery's long functions (also forEach,map,filter...).jquery is made for ie6... so it has to do alot of checks even for the simples things.